# Big shape data won't load in GeoServer

Tags: google-maps, geoserver

I'm trying to load a 500MB shape file into GeoServer and get it to respond to a client request within a reasonable time frame (it currently doesn't respond even after 30mins of waiting).  I want it to deliver image tiles; I'm using Google Maps API v3 ImageMapType to automatically request the correct tiles using the GeoServer WMS URL.  The layer consists of hundreds of thousands of polygons for coastal Tasmania - so the layer is very sparse.  I've tried:

- Creating a tile cache (but the ETA is 15 years in zoom range 13 to 18) and it creates a lot of blank tiles (est. >95%)
- Removing all attributes in the layer before loading into GeoServer (still waited an hour for it to begin seeding tile cache and still gave no progress)
- Merging the polygons so there are only 10 polygons in the layer (same behaviour)
- Using the bounds options in the tile cache (same behaviour)
- [edit] Reprojecting the layer into EPSG:900913 (same behaviour)
- Cutting the layer into 12 sections to reduce empty space, loading them as a Layer Group, and seeding the tile cache from this (even 1 of these layers wouldn't begin seeding - too big still?)

The next option we're looking at is breaking the layer into 1km grids and loading all 8000 layers as a Layer Group.  I'm doubtful this will work.  However 1 of these layers DID work when seeding the cache - and it only took a few seconds for all zoom levels.

**How do I get GeoServer to serve this large, sparse data?**  Surely other people have this issue?  Do I need to do something special with the layer itself?  Or is there something in GeoServer that I should be configuring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start: a 500MB map should be peanuts for GeoServer, unless you bought your hardware well over a decade ago. I work with much larger datasets on a daily basis.

Perhaps you let GeoServer access the shapefile directly from disk?

I'd recommend the following setup:

- Make sure you have enough RAM installed. I just saw that I could buy 24GB for less than 80 euros. That should be enough to cache your database entirely;
- Install Postgres with PostGIS extensions;
- To make sure that no re-projection is necessary, you can pre-convert all coordinates to Google's marcator projection (EPSG:9009l3);
- Make sure you have a spatial index on the geometry column;
- If your map is static, you can pre-render the tiles. This is really going to be a big boost in performance. Try to find until which zoomlevel you can pre-render within a reasonable time. The zoomed-in images are usually faster anyway, because fewer elements are involved to create the image;

Furthermore, I doubt that you're ever going to get a result if it took 30 minutes. At least the webserver already timed out way before that. Download the image manually by pasting the URL. If you don't see a picture, then open the downloaded image in a text editor: there might be a textual error message in the picture file instead of binary data. That error message usually describes what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Wouter, I'd just like to clarify my setup.  I've added the layer using the Shapefile option where you browse to the location on disk.  Where does Postgres+PostGIS come into it?  I assumed that was for spatial data stored in the database itself, versus loading it from disk.  Or are you saying disk access is the bottleneck?

I currently have 8GB RAM and a Core i7 on this machine.  I would very much like to pre-render the tiles, but it never gets anywhere...